# CSS Gradient Chat Bubble

Tags: html, css

I want to create a message area where the chat bubbles change color gradients as the user scrolls. The code I have should work, but I don't know what I'm missing

I applied mixed-blend-mode to the wrapper or the bubbles, but what I see on my screen seems greyed out.

```css
.sent-bubble {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 250px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.received-bubble {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-right: 200px;
  max-width: 250px;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.message-display-center:after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 143, 178) 0%, rgb(167, 151, 255) 50%, rgb(0, 229, 255)100%);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.message-display-center {
  max-height: 350px;
  text-align: justify;
  max-height: 320px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-display-center">
  <div class="sent-bubble">
    Hi There Adam!
  </div>

  <div class="received-bubble">
    Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate !
  </div>
</div>
```

The expected result should show the bubbles changing gradient as the user scrolls. And if the greying out effect in my code can be eliminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set `beckground-color` to `pseudo` selector you need to set static `height` and `width`.

but in our case you need full screen `background-color` so i use `position:fixed;` and `top:0;` `bottom:0;` `left:0;` `right:0;`

but if you need this only the height of `<div class="message-display-cente">` div then you must use `position:absolute` at the place of `position:fixed;` in `.message-display-cente::after` and set `potion:relative` to the parent div here`.message-display-cente` like below..

```
.message-display-center{
  position:relative;
}
    .message-display-center:after{
         content: '';
         background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 143,178) 0%, rgb(167,151, 255)50%, rgb(0,229, 255)100%);
         mix-blend-mode: screen;
         position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;

     }
```

```css
.sent-bubble{
    margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px; padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*text-align: center;*/


    background: black;
    color: white;

 }

.received-bubble{
    margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px; padding-left: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-right: 200px;
    max-width: 250px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    background: black;
    color: white;

 }

.message-display-center:after{
     content: '';
     background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 143,178) 0%, rgb(167,151, 255)50%, rgb(0,229, 255)100%);
     mix-blend-mode: screen;
     position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

 }

 .message-display-center{
     max-height:350px;
     text-align:justify;
     max-height: 320px;
     overflow-x: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;


}
```

```html
<div class="message-display-center">

              <div class="sent-bubble">
                                Hi There Adam! 
                            </div>

                            <div class="received-bubble">
                                Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate !
                                Ahoy mate !  Ahoy mate !  Ahoy mate !
                                Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy 
                                mate !
                                Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate ! Ahoy mate !
                            </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## CSS

in your CSS for ::after : missing some imp properties like

.message-display-center::after {

```
content: '';
background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 143,178) 0%, rgb(167,151, 255) 50%, rgb(0,229, 255)100%);
mix-blend-mode: screen;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

You have applied the background linear gradiant for body. To change bubble apply  ::after for buble class and give

position:relative

to parent class